# Test Case Management Software

Tags: test-management, manual-testing

I currently write automated tests using WebDriver/Selenium 2 and utilize the Page Object model. I'd like to start documenting manual tests but our current process is only creating test cases in MS word documents.

What I'd like is software that supports scenario linking or modules similar to the Page Object model I use for automation. What this means is that if a user needs to login I'd like the software to be able to call the login module, if something changes on the login module I only need to make the change one time and have it bubble back up to my manual test scripts.

Is anyone aware of a software that allows this type of modular/scenario linking?

I've looked at [TestLink](http://www.teamst.org) and [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/), but unsure if these technologies support scenario linking.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I document test cases in a Wiki.  I use Mediawiki for a Wiki engine.  With Mediawiki, you can write test case fragments (like the login scenario you described) in a separate page, and then either hyperlink to that page or reference the fragment in other pages, which causes the contents of the fragment to be displayed within the page.  If you need to update that fragment, you just change its page; the changes will automatically appear in any page that references that fragment.

Aside from Mediawiki, there are many other free and commercial Wiki engines, each with its own advantages and disadvantages.  You can use your favorite search engine to research a Wiki engine appropriate to your own needs.

There are also test case management systems that may help with more than just documenting your test cases.  I do not use one, but if you type "test case management system" into your favorite search engine, you should find many relevant links.

Comment: After reading this suggestion I've given the approach a trial run. I'm using some templates and some parser functions to create "Scenario" pages which contain `[[TestStep|NameOfTestStep]]` to import a test step using transclusion. I've tried to set it up so that if a test step doesn't exist, it lets you create a new page with preloaded template. I'm trying to greate a backlog of test steps (Login to app, Create new report etc) which can be collated into Scenarios, and then Scenarios can be imported into Test Plans.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [Test Collab](http://www.testcollab.com).
Though it's a new product but it's really easy to use with great UI.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [Seapine Test Case Manager](http://www.seapine.com).

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my experience. You could try to use TestRail Test case management system. TestRail has great UI, integrates with bugtrackers, great visualazing, easy to create great test reports, has own API, could join external requirements and a lot of other nice features. Our QA team using this great tool more than 2 years and still happy. For more details: http://www.gurock.com/testrail/

Answer (score 0):

This link has 21 test management tools reviewed http://qtp.blogspot.com/2010/07/test-management.html

Comment: Hi @Nitin - just a tip, rather than just providing a link, it's preferable to try to summarise the content(at least a little), especially if that's your whole answer. Unfortunately the reviews at the page linked don't really answer the question - I wasn't able to tell from them whether the tools would support his needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you came across a suitable tool, but you may want to consider a tool that I have been developing [TestLodge](http://www.testlodge.com)

The main aim of the tool is to keep people productive by only providing the essential features to get the job done, which is ideal for someone who is just starting out with this kind of testing.

Hope this helps,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

You can try RTH(http://sourceforge.net/projects/rth/). It supports a lot of stuffs but I am not sure of the support of scenario linking

Comment: Hi, Shantonu, this answer is probably not all that helpful here, since the original question has already been answered. If there's a reason you feel RTH is a better solution than the marked answer, perhaps you could edit your answer to explain this?

Comment: Hi Kate, RTH can be customize to support remotely running process. Because of that I refer that as relevant answer. From RTH I have seen making build(integrating with build servers).

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of test management tools listed here (under 'Test Management') - http://www.ministryoftesting.com/resources/software-testing-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to mention another test management tool, I use Robot Framework. I really like the keyword-driven framework. In a short summary, you define a new keyword "Login to XXX", and then all test cases can just use it. When you want to change the actual steps in the login process you change it in one place -- the keyword definition. Also, if done right, the test cases can be understood very very easily.

Here is how one test case example looks like, it tests for a successful login on a portal page. The assertion can be improved but you get the idea.

```
Open Browser      ${_PORTAL}    ${CHOSEN_BROWSER}
Input Text        login_user    ${VALID_USER}
Input Text        login_pass    ${VALID_PASSWORD}
Page Should Not Contain  Invalid Email or Password
Click Button      xpath=//html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/fieldset/div/button
Page Should Not Contain  Invalid Email or Password
Close Browser
```

Answer (score -1):

You could refer how they make it linked for qTest tool - cloud-based Test Management. http://www.qasymphony.com/qtest-features.html

Comment: Nam, I'm seeing a pattern here, and it's not a good one. Please refer to our policy on self-promotion. Specifically, "you must disclose your affiliation in your answers" and "If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons". There also is no accompanying material to explain why the tools are a good fit for the OP. If you'd like a perfect example (from yesterday!) of how self-promotion is supposed to work here, check out http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/5058/65

Comment: Sorry for this. I'll notice it for later posts. Thx for advice.