# Test reporting tools

Tags: manual-testing

I am creating a set of test cases and I am looking for a better solution for what I am doing. I am currently using Microsoft excel to create a spreadsheet for all my tests and reporting. I am looking for an open source test management tool that I can create tests for products and have it generate reports.

Comment: You may also look into commercial tools which offer free experience for limited number of team members. I believe  http://www.kualitee.com/ is a good choice as it offers free access to all features for 20 members team.

Comment: Isn't that a candidate for community-wiki? There isn't one best answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing Automated testing I would suggest TestNG as mentioned previously along with ExtentReport

ExtentReport is used to create a report based on the results from your TestNG tests.

Example - **http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/ExtentJava.html**

You can use it as either a **Logger** or **Listener**

**Logger**

The logger function is where you add a log to your test step and this will then be logged in the report along with the status of the test eg. Pass/Fail/Skip.

Example - **http://www.ontestautomation.com/creating-html-reports-for-your-selenium-tests-using-extentreports/**

**Listener**

You can also use ExtentReport as a listener. This is where ExtentReport will listen in on the tests being run and then generate a report based on your results. This is useful if you don't want to add in extra code to your test classes. You then specify the listener in your TestNG test XML file.

Example - **http://www.ontestautomation.com/using-the-extentreports-testng-listener-in-selenium-page-object-tests/**

You can also specify the dependency if you are using a Maven style project.

Here - **http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports/2.40.2**

This is for version 2.40.2. They now have however version 2.41.0 released.

Comment: Hi Colin, what is ExtentReport and how does using it make it substantially different from TestNG? Thanks!

Comment: Its just a JAR file that can be used as an add-on to test NG. You can use it as a Logger or a Listener. In terms of the Logger you can use it to log each of your test steps. With a Listener you can just create a Listener class that will listen in on your tests and generate a report based on the results. You just need to specify the Listener class in your TestNG Testing XML. I will update my questions and put in some useful links for you.

Comment: @corsiKa Thank you. Hopefully it helps somebit, do not hesitate to contact me further about it I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: @corsiKa I updated my question with more links as my reputation is now higher.

Answer (score 1):

TestLink is one of the major open source test management tools. (I have some experience using it). You should also take a look at the answer to [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/test-case-management-software?rq=1), which include links to some detailed lists of testing tools.

Answer (score 0):

TestLink is the open source test management tool, with good reporting tools.

**Following is the screenshot of report from TestLink:**

[image]

If wish to try it before you start using it, following is the demo link for TestLink

[Demo Link for TestLink](https://www.softaculous.com/demos/TestLink)

Answer (score 0):

fitnesse is one option

http://fitnesse.org/

From the site:

*FitNesse is a tool for specifying and verifying application acceptance criteria (requirements). It acts as a bridge between the different stakeholders (disciplines) in a software delivery process. It's wiki server makes it easy to document the software.It's testexecution capabilities allow you to verify the documentation against the software, ensuring the documentation remains up to date and the software is not facing regression.
For this to work, the tests should be defined on a business level, in conjunction with business representatives. They are basically business requirements, laid out in a way easy to understand by all stakeholders. When your requirements are unambiguous, they can be automatically verified with your application.*

Answer (score 0):

testng is another option

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

*TestNG is a testing framework designed to simplify a broad range of testing needs, from unit testing (testing a class in isolation of the others) to integration testing (testing entire systems made of several classes, several packages and even several external frameworks, such as application servers).
Writing a test is typically a three-step process:
    Write the business logic of your test and insert TestNG annotations in your code.
    Add the information about your test (e.g. the class name, the groups you wish to run, etc...) in a testng.xml file or in build.xml.
    Run TestNG.*